# Passport Configuration Session Optional?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, pg, passport-local

I have looked elsewhere for this answer, but I have not found anything.

The passport documentation on configuration: http://passportjs.org/docs/configure implies that the 'session' portion is optional. Later in the documentation it also implies this when referring to persistent login sessions:

> If your application uses persistent login sessions, passport.session()
>   middleware must also be used.

I know most real world applications would require a persistent session, but for learning purposes, I am trying to build this up incrementally and want to have login work and redirect to a success page without passport trying to serialize my user.

Currently, I have both bad password and bad username redirecting correctly to a failure page. When I enter good credentials and locate the user in the db, I don't redirect to the success page. Instead I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed to serialize user into session
```

I know adding the following will resolve the issue:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

How do I configure passport to not serialize my user? Is this even possible?

Comment: Just use sessions, it's literally just couple lines of code to get it working. `app.use('session(...));` and `app.use(passport.session());` you gonna need to install express sessions package `npm install express-session` and require it before you can use it `var session = require('express-session')`. That's it.

Comment: @Molda some people prefer to use a different method of tracking the authentication state (like using JWT's, or when you are implementing a webapp that isn't going to be consumed by browsers), so I think it's a valid question :)

Comment: @robertklep I totally agree. But as mentioned in question **"for learning purposes"** I thought it would be simplest and quickest way to get it working, I definitely didn't try to recommend it as a best solution. I use JWT myself.

Comment: @Molda yeah, if it's just to get things working, it's easiest to just enable them :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll get that error if you don't explicitly [disable session support](http://passportjs.org/docs#disable-sessions) in the call to `passport.authenticate()`.

Comment: The link you provided is for disabling the use of the persistent session for authentication on subsequent requests, and instead requiring the caller to always supply the basic auth credentials. 

My question refers to an error during the login and creation of the session setup.

Comment: @MillieWalsh that sort of correct, yes, although it's not tied to [Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). It may also be that the "success" handler of the authentication sets or returns a token that should be passed to subsequent requests (combined with a custom middleware to check its validity)